# Using flash player on a 32-bit machine

Tags: firefox, flash, 32-bit

This is kind of two problems bundled together. I'll focus on only one and I'll try to be as specific as possible: I don't have flash player installed on Firefox, I started looking and it turns out that Adobe stopped their support for Linux, the solutions I find for using flash on Linux are to just switch to Chrome, but I can't do that since I'm on a 32-bit machine (Google stopped their support for 32-bit machines) And last time I used Chrome it had a major bug in wich Google services wouldn't open due to some SSL error. I also read that Pepperflash is not supported by Firefox, what should I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can install a flash player for most browsers with

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

It is not the latest version like on Windows but it works and it does still receive security updates, it works for both X86 and X64 architectures.

Chrome has no 32bit Linux version anymore, you could use chromium, it is what chrome is based on, and is very similar in design.

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

Comment: No, Chromium doesn't come with Flash. Since Google has dropped support for 32-bit, it is likely that soon there will be no way to use an up-to-date version of flash in 32-bit Chromium either.